# How to prove formally that these two definitions of Complex projective space are same?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, projective-space

**Definition:** $\mathbb CP^n$ [Complex Projective Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_projective_space) is defined as the space of lines through origin in $\mathbb C^{n+1}$.

**Definition:** $\mathbb CP^n= \frac {S^{2n+1}}{S^1}$

> How to prove formally that above two definitions of $\mathbb C P^n$ are same?

Intuitively i can see that both definitions are same but i am struggling in proving formally.Any ideas?

Comment: You have besides that $\Bbb P_2(\Bbb R)$ is homeomorphic to each of the quotient spaces deduced from (1) the sphere $S: x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ in which diametrically opposed points are identified; (2) the closed disk $\Delta: x^2+y^2\le 1$ in which the diametrically opposed points of the border are identified.You have even homeomorphism with the hemisphere (identifying what points?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered in the wikipedia article itself: One may also regard $\mathbb{C}P^n$ as a quotient of the unit $(2n + 1)$-sphere in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ under the action of $U(1)$:
$$
\mathbb{C}P^n\cong S^{2n+1}/U(1)\cong  S^{2n+1}/S^1. 
$$
Actually, is has been shown on MSE already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018078/how-to-prove-that-s2n1-s1-is-homeomorphic-to-mathbb-cpn-under-a-given?rq=1). For $n=1$ see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323116/mathbbc-mathbbp1-is-homeomorphic-to-s2).

Comment: In wikipedia it is given as a fact with no proof. Thank you :)

Comment: Well, the idea with $U(1)$ action is given, but some details are skipped, this is right. But the reader is assumed to fill in the details.

Comment: I was having trouble in filling the details.Thanks for the link :-)